# Create a model on the server with an Id that was set on the client

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a way to create a model with `POST` request event if the `id` for the model is set in browser. So normally backbone will make a `PUT` request when the id still exists in the model, and I cant find a way to work around this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the sync method in the model.

```
sync: function(method, model, options) {
    if (method === 'update') {
        method = 'create';
    }
    return Backbone.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning on  [emulateHTTP](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateHTTP).